# Updating/Setting relationships in Core Data when users enter data from different tableviews

Tags: iphone, core-data, many-to-many, one-to-many, key-value-observing

I have 3 entities in my core data app:  Criteria--->>Rank(has 1 attribute:criteriaRank)<<---Option

Let's a user enters a few options in a tableview and then goes to another tableview where they enter some number of criteria.  The way my app is suppose to behave is that for each criteria that the user enters, it should create a Rank object so that when a user goes back to the options tableview and select an option, it should allow them to rank each criteria they entered.

Right now, when I create a new criteria I set it the following way,

```
//Create new Criteria and set its context
Criteria *newCriteria = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Criteria" inManagedObjectContext:context];


for (Option *anOption in sortedOptions) {
    Rank *newCriteriaRank = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Rank" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newCriteria addRankingsObject:newCriteriaRank];
    [anOption addRankingsObject: newCriteriaRank];
}
```

But then what if I have to go back and add another option?
I guess what I am asking is what is a good way to set the relationships so that each side is updated when the other get changed.

I looked in KVO and Notifications, but I am not sure exactly where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your .xcdatamodel, select one of the entities. Under relationship, select the relationship in question and then select an Inverse. This will help maintain your RFI.

This assumes that you have one relationship on each entity that points at the other. If you don't have relationships on both entities, then you'll have to add one in order to get inverse working properly.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I always make sure that all the entities I create have inverse relationships since thats the recommendation according to apple docs.  I still have the issue that when I add a new option, it does not get its rank entities created and set for it. Is there a better place where this relation needs to be set?

Comment: Managed Objects do not get created automatically for you. You have to manually create objects and set relationships via code.

Comment: I guess I didn't ask my question the right way. I have created the managed objects.  If you look at the code above, every time it created a Criteria managed object, it loops through all the Options managed object and creates a Rank managed object and sets both sides of the relationship.  Let's say later, I decided to change my mind and delete a criteria and add a new one, now I have a criteria without a relationship set.  I read somewhere on StackOverflow to use some sort of a callback option that will go back are loop through the already created managed objects,

Comment: create a set of Rank objects and set the relationship but I am not sure how to implement something like that.  I apologize for not being clear, given my lack of experience with objective-c/iOS I am not sure how to describe what I am aiming for. Can KVO be used as a trigger that new Options object has been created and that certain actions need to be taken?